# How to find number of rows in heroku database

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku

The title pretty much sums up my question, but here are more details:

I'm running a script to import rows into a heroku database. I started getting errors:

```
<class 'django.db.utils.DatabaseError'> current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`
```

The script runs smoothly on my localhost so I'm not looking for problems there. I recently received an email from heroku stating that I'm "Approaching row limit for dev database"

I'm assuming I hit the row limit but I'd like to confirm this before taking further action.

Does anyone know how I can find my current row count for the whole database? (I know I can just do a count on each table but I'm hoping there's a cleaner way)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you have the heroku cli tool, this will give you, among other things, the number of rows in your database

```
heroku pg:info -a your_app
```

Also given are your plan type, the db status, the number of current connections, postgres version, when the db was created, the number of rows in your plan, the data size, the number of tables and if your db has any fork/follow options activated.

Comment: awesome, heroku did have something easier.  much appreciated

Comment: Hmm. On my app this command doesn’t tell me the number of rows. It gives me all the properties you mentioned except the number of rows used and the number of rows in my plan. (I know that the latter is 10 million, since this app is on the “basic” plan.)

Comment: also not seeing rows - using latest heroku 2.35.0

Comment: FWIW Only dev and basic tier databases have row count available through `pg:info`.

Comment: As @zem and jpwynn have suggested, it seems that pg:info _doesn't_ return the row count on the "Basic" plan. Hopefully this means that they don't enforce the 10M row limit!

Comment: Same here. Row count reported for Dev plan, but not Basic.

Comment: Row count is not reported on production tier or basic plans.

Comment: Is this to make you upgrade from basic to Crane? :)

Comment: You can also just type `heroku pg:info` without specifying the app if you are already in the app directory

Answer (score 23):

This will give you the approximate count of all rows within your database:

```
 SELECT sum(reltuples) from pg_class where relname IN (SELECT c.relname
 FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
 LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
 WHERE c.relkind = 'r'
 AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
 AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
 AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
 AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid));
```

Though the error message indicates some error on your database, likely a constraint violation versus something with your insert privileges being revoked.

Comment: thanks for the sql statement.  I was hoping Heroku had something easier but this worked perfectly.

you're right about assuming it's a constraint violation but half the imports worked so I don't think it's that.  I am over my row limit so hopefully that's the issue

Answer (score 8):

Heroku released [a "pg-extras" toolbelt](https://blog.heroku.com/more_insight_into_your_database_with_pgextras) which can give you extra informations like the number of rows of your database.

Even if you have a higher plan than Hobby, you will get the number of rows by doing the following:

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-pg-extras
```

Then:

```
heroku pg:index_usage --app dashboard
```

This will give you the number of rows per table.

Comment: Notice you will need to have postgresql installed locally too for this to work; otherwise, you will receive an error "The local psql command could not be located"